# How to validate placeholders?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

The [Placeholders](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Tutorial#Placeholders) are available in Mojolicious.

We can access them via `$c->param( 'placeholder_name' )` as other input data from user `$c->param( 'post_or_query_param' )`

But when we access parameters after validation we use:

```
$c->validation->param( 'post_or_query_param' )
```

The `undef` is returned if `post_or_query_param` did not pass validation.

We can validate placeholders partially via [`Restrective placeholders`](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Tutorial#Restrictive-placeholders) but still access them as `$c->param( 'placeholder_name' )` (because placeholder is not available to validation object)

This often lead programmer to think that in this place of code not validated data is used because validated data is available as: `$v->param( 'xxx' )`

The placeholders is same input from user as query or post data.

**How to make placeholders available to validation object?** and access user's input in same way as other validated data:

```
$v->param( 'validated parameter name' );
```

Comment: I don't think doing that is a good idea. Those placeholders are part of the URL. In a way they are arguments (or params), but they are not _form_ parameters, and that's what validation is intended for imho. That said, I _think_ you can feed the validation object an arbitrary hash instead of relying on on its built-in magic that fetches GET and POST params.

Comment: @simbabque: I think, we should take into account **form**. The query may be **json** or **xml** and in any case data will be accessed by `$v->param(...)`. The form validation is particular case. This behavior should not be hardcoded and must relay on handlers. Which called based on `Content-Type` header. I think about all: URL, query, and POST body, as user's input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I use [OpenAPI](https://www.openapis.org) plugin and describe API using this format. Placeholder parameters also will be validated through schema (just like Query/JSON/Form/XML parameters).

OpenAPI validator is based on JSON Schema Validator and is rich. Supports min, max, patterns, enums, deep structures etc.

[Read article about Mojolicious and OpenAPI](http://thorsen.pm/perl/programming/2015/07/05/mojolicious-swagger2.html).

Here is [example of validation schema](https://github.com/akzhan/perl-YourCompany-Project/blob/master/config/api.json) and [controller](https://github.com/akzhan/perl-YourCompany-Project/blob/master/lib/YourCompany/App/Api/Project.pm).

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: There is not problem with query. Question is about placeholder. which are not available to validation object

Comment: OpenAPI supports placeholder parameters validation too. Thanks, have fixed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this solution: put placeholder into `->input`

```
# GET /tariffs/:tariff_id
my $v =  $c->validation;

# Solution: how to make placeholder available to validation:
my $placeholders =  $self->match->stack->[-1];
@{ $v->input }{ keys %$placeholders } =  values %$placeholders;

# etc.
$v->required( tariff_id =>  [ data_exists =>  $self, '!Tariff' ] );
return ...   if $v->has_error;

my $tariff =  $v->param( 'tariff_id' );
```